# Projection of the third dual of a Banach space onto the first dual

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $j_X:X\rightarrow X^{**}$ denote the canonical embedding.

I've read several articles where it is assumed that the reader is familiar with the idea that there is a norm one projection from $X^{***}$ to $X^*$. More precisely, $P:=j_{X^*}(j_X)^*$ seems to be that projection. However, I couldn't find any material that would explain it in detail, and I can't really figure out how this operator works on my own.

If we take $x^{***} \in X^{***}$, then what exactly happens to it when we apply $P$, in other words, what kind of an operator is $j_{X^*}(j_X)^*x^{***}: X^{**} \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an exercise in writing down the definitions. Recall the general definitions of $j_X$, and of the dual operator. Apply this here. In the end, you get

$$(j_{X^*} \circ (j_X)^*)(v)(u) = u(v \circ j_X)$$

for $v \in X^{***}$ and $u \in X^{**}$.

Answer (score 1):

$P(x^{***})(x) = x^{***}(j_X(x))$

Comment: ... where $P = (j_X)^*$.