# Banach spaces not isomorphic to $\ell^p(S)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

We know that every Hilbert space is unitarily equivalent to $\ell^2(S)$, for a set $S$ of suitable cardinality.

Is there a Banach space which is NOT isomorphic to $L^p(X)$, for any $1\leq p \leq \infty$, and any measure space $X$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note the following three facts

- $c_0$ is not a dual space, because otherwise [it must be complemented in its second dual](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298660/projection-of-the-third-dual-of-a-banach-space-onto-the-first-dual), but [it is not](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132520/complement-of-c-0-in-ell-infty/132586#132586).
- $L_p(X)$ is dual for $1<p<\infty$ because $L_p(X)=L_\frac{p}{p-1}(X)^*$
- $L_\infty(X)$ is dual because $L_\infty(X)=L_1(X)^*$

So $c_0$ is not isomorphic to $L_p(X)$ for any measure space $X$ and $1< p\leq\infty$. It is remains to handle the case $p=1$.

Note another two facts

- $c_0^*=\ell_1$, and $\ell_1$ is infinite dimensional and separable
- $L_1(X)^*=L_\infty(X)$ and $L_\infty(X)$ is infinite dimensional and **nonseparable**.

Thus duals of $c_0$ and $L_1(X)$ can't be isomorphic, and a fortiori neither does $c_0$ and $L_1(X)$.

P.S.

Almost always there is no simple way to show that two Banach spaces are not isomorphic. Deal with it.

Comment: thank you! that was very instructive. Now, of course, another question comes to mind: can you embed every Banach space in a $L^p$ space? Maybe I'll post it as a separate question.

Comment: @Amudhan it should be a separate question and I think the answer is no for $1\leq p<\infty$ and yes for $p=\infty$.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, your link only shows $c_0$ is not isometrically isomorphic to a dual space. (Of course, it is true that $c_0$ is not isomorphic to a dual space.)

Comment: @DavidMitra, thank you! I'll fix it